# How to serialize object in XML while flattening the internal hierarchy of properties within

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization

I am serializing an object using [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer(v=VS.90).aspx), specifying Attributes within my object to give instructions to the XmlSerializer, like so:

```
[XmlType("FooElement")]
public class Foo {

    [XmlAttribute("Type")]
    public string fooType;

    [XmlElement("Name")]
    public string Name;

    [XmlElement("Bar")]
    public Bar BarObject;
}

public class Bar {
    [XmlElement("Message")]
    public string BarString;
    [XmlElement("From")]
    public string FromName;
}
```

When an object of type Foo is serialized, the following XML is generated:

```
<Foo Type="TypeName">
  <Name>Name of Foo</Name>
  <Bar>
     <Message>5:00 Somewhere</Message>
     <From>Jane Smith</From>
  </Bar>
</Foo>
```

What I want is for all data within Foo to be flattened to the same level, like so:

```
<Foo Type="TypeName">
  <Name>Name of Foo</Name>
  <Message>5:00 Somewhere</Message>
  <From>Jane Smith</From>
</Foo>
```

It is important for my needs that Foo and Bar remain separate classes. Aside from merging classes, How would I go about flattening the elements of Foo into a single level when serialized as XML? It would be best if it could be done through use of [Property] tags. I am open to switching my method of XML Serialization.

Edit: I have switched to the [XmlWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.aspx) class. This will let me write XML elements in the hierarchy that I am looking for. The program consuming XML produced here is much simpler than the C# XML tools. The simpler parser was having difficulty with XmlSerializer generated XML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it

```
void Main()
{
    var foo = new Foo
    {
        Name = "name",
        fooType = "type",
        BarObject = new Bar { BarString = "bar"}
    };

    var s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Foo));
    using (var writer = new StringWriter())
    {
        s.Serialize(writer, foo);
        writer.ToString().Dump();
    }
}


public class Foo {

    [XmlAttribute("Type")]
    public string fooType;

    [XmlElement("Name")]
    public string Name;

    [XmlElement("Message")]
    public Bar BarObject;
}

public class Bar {

    [XmlText]
    public string BarString;
}
```

The output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Foo xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Type="type">
  <Name>name</Name>
  <Message>bar</Message>
</Foo>
```

Comment: This looks great. One question: can this be scaled to work so that if Bar has more than one element (Message, Date, etc), each element within Bar appears within the Foo element in XML?

Comment: @ford If you add more properties/fields to the `Bar` class? Sure, why not. Just add and mark them as `[XmlElement]`. Otherwise I am not sure what you mean.

Comment: Thanks for the request for clarification. I've edited my question.

Comment: @ford I see... no, that is not possible to my knowledge. I question why would you want that, since serialized XML data is kinda meant to represent the object tree you are serializing. Even the sample I provided is a hack, since `XmlText` serializes as a node (text node) that is a child of node `Message`. Maybe if you presented your higher level problem I could think of a workaround or convince you that your requirement is invalid.

Comment: knowing this is good enough. I'll take this from a different angle and eliminate the requirement that the hierarchy be flattened. I mostly wanted to make the XML simpler for the reader on the other side, and it looks like this method would complicate things instead.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a way to do this without adding properties to Foo that map to corresponding properties of Bar. For example:

```
[XmlType("FooElement")]
public class Foo {

    [XmlAttribute("Type")]
    public string fooType;

    [XmlElement("Name")]
    public string Name;

    [XmlIgnore()]
    public Bar BarObject;

    [XmlElement("Message")]
    public string BarMessage
    {
       get {
          return this.Bar.BarString;
       }
       set {
          this.Bar.BarString = value;
       }
}

public class Bar {
    public string BarString;
}
```